# How to stop Audio when App closes Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

In iOS this is stadard. But on Android when I play aution in the app and close the app the audio still plays. How can I stop this?

This is what I have:

```
vid = document.getElementById("audio2");

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime = 0;
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime = 0;
});


vid.onended = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.pause = true;
    }, 0);
}

$scope.pause = true;

$scope.playAudio = function() {
    vid.play();
    $scope.pause = false;
}

$scope.pauseAudio = function() {
    vid.pause();
    $scope.pause = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your app to behave but you could use cordova's *resume* and *pause* events to stop audio when leaving/closing your app and starting it when entering your app again:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

// called when entering your app
function onResume() {
   var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('your view element')).scope();
   scope .playAudio();
}

// called when leaving your app 
function onPause() {
   var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('your view element')).scope();
   scope.pauseAudio();
}
```

For more info: [resume](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.resume.html) and [pause](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.pause.html).